Android android.os.TransactionTooLargeException, Growing size of android:support:fragments
I have a problem with the android application.
The entire application is based on one main activity and many fragments that the activity manages.
Fragments are changed by calling a method from the main activity:
public void selectFragment(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        if (isFinishing() || isDestroyed()) {
            return;
        }

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().isStateSaved()) {
            showFragmentCommitToast();
            return;
        }

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (id) {
            case Constants.FRAGMENT_LOGIN:
                fragment = LoginFragment.newInstance();
                break;
        //other fragments
        }

        if ((bundle != null) && (fragment != null))
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (id == Constants.FRAGMENT_LOGIN ||             
                //other fragments)
        ) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, Constants.FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
        } else {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, Constants.FRAGMENT_TAG).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    }

In crashlytics I get an error:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 531748 bytes
I don't pass any large data between fragments.
I used TooLargeTool and noticed that MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState was saving more and more data as I moved through different fragments.
The size of android:support:fragments increases and causes an application error. How to clean android:support:fragments?

are you putting data to the instancestate anywhere?

I have several fragments where I write the index like this:
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); bundle.putInt(Constants.BUNDLE_INDEX, index); mActivity.selectFragment(Constants.FRAGMENT_MY_FRAGMENT, bundle);

This might be the reason for the TransactionTooLargeException because you keep adding data to the instance state and dont clear it afterwards, the limit is 1MB

This is only one int, do you think that maybe if it is not cleared it may cause an error? How to properly clean such data?

Do you have a lot of bitmaps or images in your UI?
